# class com.google.protobuf.HBaseZeroCopyByteString cannot access its superclass com.google.protobuf.LiteralByteString

Tags: apache-spark, hbase

I am getting the below error when running the spark application:

```
16/01/08 15:25:48 INFO SchemaMetadata: Entering synchronized block to initiate
16/01/08 15:25:48 INFO SchemaMetadata: Initializing SchemaMetadata
16/01/08 15:25:48 INFO SchemaMetadata: Schema initialized from database
16/01/08 15:25:48 INFO SchemaMetadata: Registering for notifications
16/01/08 15:25:49 WARN HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Encountered problems when prefetch hbase:meta table:
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.google.protobuf.HBaseZeroCopyByteString cannot access its superclass com.google.protobuf.LiteralByteString
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.translateException(RpcRetryingCaller.java:210)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:121)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.getRowOrBefore(HTable.java:714)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MetaScanner.metaScan(MetaScanner.java:144)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.prefetchRegionCache(HConnectionManager.java:1159)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(HConnectionManager.java:1223)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:1111)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:1068)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess.findDestLocation(AsyncProcess.java:361)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncProcess.submit(AsyncProcess.java:306)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.backgroundFlushCommits(HTable.java:964)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.flushCommits(HTable.java:1252)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.put(HTable.java:924)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.google.protobuf.HBaseZeroCopyByteString cannot access its superclass com.google.protobuf.LiteralByteString
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.RequestConverter.buildRegionSpecifier(RequestConverter.java:930)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.RequestConverter.buildGetRowOrBeforeRequest(RequestConverter.java:133)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.getRowOrBefore(ProtobufUtil.java:1497)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable$2.call(HTable.java:710)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable$2.call(HTable.java:708)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:114)
... 31 more
```

The problem here i found is the class loader is loading the LiteralByteString class from Spark assembly jar earlier in the JVM and then loading the HBaseZeroCopyByteString class from the user jar. That's why it is creating the problem.

Spark provide one property to load the user jar first in JVM that is `spark.executor.userClassPathFirst`, But unfortunately not getting luck in this as well.

Please suggest solution if anyone has encountered and resolved this problem.

Comment: Hi, did you find solution for this problem.?

Comment: Yeah, I used maven shading with relocation for protobuf dependency and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's looking that while running spark job they didn't found hbase-protocol jar in class-path.

Please try below options to solve given issue,

1. export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/usr/hdp/2.5.4.0-121/hbase/lib/hbase-protocol-1.1.2.2.5.4.0-121.jar
2. Add below properties in spark-submit

   - --driver-class-path /usr/hdp/2.5.4.0-121/hbase/lib/hbase-protocol-1.1.2.2.5.4.0-121.jar \
   - --driver-java-options "-Dspark.driver.extraClassPath=/usr/hdp/2.5.4.0-121/hbase/lib/hbase-protocol-1.1.2.2.5.4.0-121.jar" \
   - --conf "spark.executor.extraClassPath=/usr/hdp/2.5.4.0-121/hbase/lib/hbase-protocol-1.1.2.2.5.4.0-121.jar" \

Hope so your problem will be solve. Please reply me if in case any query..